# StringBuilder vs "+" in JDK >= 9

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, string-concatenation

According to https://dzone.com/articles/jdk-9jep-280-string-concatenations-will-never-be-t, I have the following question:

Should I always use `+` instead of `StringBuilder` when building/concatenating strings? As I understood, `+` uses invokedynamic so it is always faster (and more memory friendly) then `StringBuilder`. Is this right?

Comment: Unless you're concatenating with a loop or something similar, use `+`.

Comment: Are there any other considerations to take into account when replacing all the `StringBuilders` with `+`?

Comment: As Slaw mentioned, the actual use-case of `StringBuilder` is not a simple single concat. It is for when you concat multiple times over time, maybe with a loop. And then it is still the better choice. Stuff like `foo + bar + baz` is not an issue.

Comment: What about [`String.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) ?

Comment: The problem with `+` comes once you do `for (...) { foo += bar; }`. Optimizations can sometimes be smart enough to convert that pattern as well, but still often fail. Especially if things get more complicated. Use a `StringBuilder` for concats over time or during loops.